# Understanding Pretty() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the function `pretty()` in R and having trouble.

```
temp <- pretty(1:5,n=5)
# temp is 1 2 3 4 5

temp <- pretty(1:6, n=6)
# temp is 1 2 3 4 5 6

temp <- pretty(1:3, n=3)
#temp is 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0

temp <- pretty(1:3, n=2)
#temp is 1 2 3

temp <- pretty(1:15, n=3)
#temp is 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
```

I tried to read the documentation but still very lost of the bottom 3 examples I provided above.

Any help would be much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get a different output for some of the commands.  What is the R version

Comment: Try `pretty(rnorm(5))`. The function returns *round* numbers, in a certain sense. I find it more useful for real numbers.

Comment: Is the last one a typo that should be n=8? With n=3 I get 0   5  10  15 which is exactly 3 intervals as requested. The second to the last is 2 intervals, exactly as requested (1  2  3). The third example asks for 3 intervals which would be 1  1.67  2.33  3 and that is not pretty at all so it gives you 4 intervals.

Comment: What part of the documentation isn't clear?  All except the last (which you posted incorrectly) follow it as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help! The last one is a typo. It should be pretty(1:15, n=5). I am mainly confused because when you do pretty(1:5,5) you get 1,2,3,4,5. Then pretty(1:6,6), you get 1,2,3,4,5,6. However, when you do pretty(1:3,3), you don't get 1,2,3 anymore. I understand that 1,2,3 only has 2 intervals. But the inconsistency tricked me up a little.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**: `pretty` returns somewhat fuzzy results. It follows certain patterns but it cannot be used to create vectors according to exact specifications and (I believe) that is not intended.

**Details**

I guess those examples are not ideal to show the effects of `pretty()`. And the way `pretty`works is not easily predictable. I usually remind myself that it was implemented to create reasonable tick marks for charts. In a chart you usually need a good first and last value and equal steps in between. That has two consequences:

- In a chart the starting tick must be less or equal than my `min(x)` data point and the last tick must greater of equal than `max(x)`.
- A chart needs **at least one tick mark in the middle** (start and end only doesn't seem reasonable to me). My guess is that is why `n=2` does not work. In a chart I usually do not need exact tick marks, either. The idea behind pretty is to just give you some reasonable tick marks based on **any** data.
- A third principle that may help understanding `pretty`: the function ignores any intermediate steps that you put in. It extracts the min and max and goes on from there. That means, `pretty(1:5)` or `pretty(c(1, 5))` should not make a difference.

Let us look closer. This gives a result that explains it a bit:

```
pretty (c(105,543))
[1] 100 200 300 400 500 600
```

So, we get a "balanced" vector. With balanced I mean that you get equal steps and round start and end points. In our example it rounds 105 down to 100 and 543 up to 600. Since the end points have a base of 100 the tick marks have, too.

```
pretty (c(105,543), n=3)
[1] 0 200 400 600
```

It cannot give us `100 300 500` because 500 < 543. Why it doesn't keep `n=3` and give us `0 300 600` instead, I cannot say either. But when you request `n=7` pretty cannot return that many intermediate steps with steps of 100. `pretty`tries to stay as close as possible to the min, max and the n. It switches to a step size of 50.

```
pretty (c(105,543), n=7)
[1] 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500 550
```